# Dual multipliers in compact set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Is there a theory that allows to restrict dual multipliers of an optimization problem to a bounded set *a-priori* based on the data of the primal problem?

As an illustration, consider the following simple linear programming problem:

$\begin{array}{ll} \max_{x\geq 0} & \langle c,x \rangle \\ \text{s.t.} & x \leq b, \end{array}$

where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \geq 0$.

The above problem is equivalent to

$\max_{x\geq 0} \min_{\lambda \geq 0} \; \langle c,x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b-x \rangle$

where $\lambda$ is the dual multiplier associated with the constraint of the primal problem. If we restrict $\lambda$ to lie in $\Lambda = \{ \lambda: ||\lambda ||_1 \leq 2||c||_1, \; \lambda \geq 0\}$, it would not change the maximin problem as the inner minimization would still enforce primal feasible solutions $x$.

**QUESTION:** Are there general results that yield similar statements about boundedness that transcend this simple situation? It would also be enough to know that there exists a bounded set $\Lambda$ without knowing its exact size.

Comment: Do you know MFCQ? MFCQ is a constraint qualification such that it has the property of the dual variables of a nonlinear/linear problem to be in a bounded set. It's quite easy to prove this property.

Comment: Hmm .. as I understand MFCQ, it formulated for one primary feasible point (typically the optimum). I am not sure how this implies that I can restrict the dual multipliers to a bounded set and still get the same result when solving the minimax problem for the Lagrangian.